# Is there any good alternative to winrar archiving utility for mac with ability to browse files before extracting them?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, archive, zip

I have so far tried Keka and Unarchiver, but they both don't allow browsing the archive content. They simply extract everything contained in the archive which is not a desirable behaviour.

Is there any free (or cheap) alternative to winrar for osx?

Comment: There were a number of QL Generators around when QuickLook was new, one of which browsed zips/archives. Now they seem to be in app packages ...

Comment: There's Zipster, which 'mounts' archives somewhat like.dmg files; inline as though they were folders

Answer (score 2):

I know you said free.. but [The Archive Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-archive-browser/id510232205?mt=12) is great and will allow you to preview the items before extracting. In my opinion, this is worth the $3.99.

Comment: Can it open files directly from the archive? Also, can I update such a file so that it re-archives it again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to quickly see what is in the archive, grab the [BetterZip QuickLook plugin](http://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator/).  It is not required to install the BetterZip application.